# Assistance creating a Sub Procedure named "(FundingResource(Balance))" Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

I am working on a program that consists of three event procedures (in other words, three different task buttons: “Select Media and Estimated Fund,” “Add Agencies,” and “Generate Report”).

When the “Select Media and Estimated Fund” button is clicked, input boxes should pop up and ask user to input a balance and that balance will be put through the formula of (Balance = Balance * (1 + interest rate).  The balance the user inputs can not be less that $500.00 or more than $3000.00.

( Estimated Budget should be calculated depending on your selection of funding resources (Funding Resource is the type of account they choose, Savings (7% interest rate) and Corporate (5% interest Rate) The calculated results should appear in the disabled textbox right next to the “Estimated Budget” textbox. If you selected two resources, each estimated budget should be summarized together. The calculation process should be called a sub procedure defined as “FundingResource (Balance)” in the event procedure.

Please be aware of the current year, 2013. Now, the report is prepared in year 2013, but the balance should be calculated for your selected year (e.g., 2015, 2016, 2017). Think about the topic of repetition to determine the ending balance during your selected year.

I have completed the code I believe but don't know how to put it into a Sub Procedure.  The code for the above question is in "btnMediaEstimatedFund".

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub btnMediaEstimatedFund_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnMediaEstimatedFund.Click

    Dim interestRate, balance, initialBalanceSavings, initialBalanceCorporate, finalBalance As Double

    txtBoxEstimatedBudget.Enabled = False
    txtBoxAgenciesNeeded.Enabled = False

    If radButtonTraditional.Checked Then

        txtBoxAgenciesNeeded.Text = 3

    ElseIf radButtonEMedia.Checked Then

        txtBoxAgenciesNeeded.Text = 2

    End If

    If checkBoxSavings.Checked Then

        interestRate = 0.07

    ElseIf checkBoxCorporate.Checked Then

        interestRate = 0.05

    ElseIf checkBoxCorporate.Checked And checkBoxSavings.Checked Then

        interestRate = 0.12

    End If

    initialBalanceSavings = InputBox("Please Enter a balance for SAVINGS account between $500.00 and $3000.00")

    If initialBalanceSavings > 3000 Then

        InputBox("Please enter a balance for SAVINGS account equal to or below $3000.00 and no less than $500.00")

    ElseIf initialBalanceSavings < 500 Then

        InputBox("Please enter a balance for SAVINGS account equal to or above $500.00 and no more than $3000.00")

    End If

     initialBalanceCorporate = InputBox("Please Enter a balance for CORPORATE account between $500.00 and $3000.00")

    If initialBalanceCorporate > 3000 Then

        InputBox("Please enter a balance for CORPORATE account equal to or below $3000.000 and no less than $500.00")

    ElseIf initialBalanceCorporate < 500 Then

        InputBox("Please enter a balance for CORPORATE account equal to or above $500.00 and no more than $3000.00")

    Else

        finalBalance = initialBalanceCorporate + initialBalanceSavings
        balance = finalBalance * (1 + interestRate)
        txtBoxEstimatedBudget.Text = balance

    End If

End Sub


Private Sub btnAddAgencies_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAddAgencies.Click

    Dim dict As Dictionary(Of String, Integer) = New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)()
    dict.Add("U-Ad ($350)", 350)
    dict.Add("Striker ($190)", 190)
    dict.Add("New Ad ($250)", 250)
    dict.Add("Samson ($530)", 530)
    dict.Add("J & R ($420)", 420)
    dict.Add("Victory ($120)", 120)

    Dim selectedItems = (From i In lstBoxAgenciesList.SelectedItems).ToArray()
    Dim total As Integer = 0

    For Each selectedItem In selectedItems

        lstBoxSelectedList.Items.Add(selectedItem)
        lstBoxAgenciesList.Items.Remove(selectedItem)

    Next

    For Each item In lstBoxSelectedList.Items

        total += dict(item)

    Next

    txtBoxEstimatedCost.Text = FormatCurrency(total.ToString())

End Sub

Private Sub btnGenerateReport_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnGenerateReport.Click

    Dim employeeLevel, year, selectedMedia, numberOfAgencies As String
    Dim today As Date

    today = CStr(dtpToday.Text)
    Name = CStr(txtBoxCreator.Text)
    employeeLevel = CStr(lstBoxResults.Text)
    year = CStr(lstBoxResults.Text)
    selectedMedia = CStr(lstBoxResults.Text)
    numberOfAgencies = CStr(txtBoxAgenciesNeeded.Text)

    dtpToday.Text = FormatDateTime(today, DateFormat.ShortDate)

    If radButtonManager.Checked Then

        employeeLevel = "Manager"

    ElseIf radButtonStaff.Checked Then

        employeeLevel = "Staff"

    End If

    If radButton2015.Checked Then

        year = "2015"

    ElseIf radButton2016.Checked Then

        year = "2016"

    ElseIf radButton2017.Checked Then

        year = "2017"

    End If

    If radButtonTraditional.Checked Then

        selectedMedia = "Traditional Media (TV, Radio)"

    ElseIf radButtonEMedia.Checked Then

        selectedMedia = "New e-Media (SNS, e-Mail)"

    End If

    lstBoxResults.Items.Add("=======================================")
    lstBoxResults.Items.Add(" ")
    lstBoxResults.Items.Add("Date : " & today)
    lstBoxResults.Items.Add(" ")
    lstBoxResults.Items.Add("Reporting Entity : " & Name)
    lstBoxResults.Items.Add(" ")
    lstBoxResults.Items.Add("Level of Employee :  " & employeeLevel)
    lstBoxResults.Items.Add(" ")
    lstBoxResults.Items.Add("=======================================")
    lstBoxResults.Items.Add(" ")
    lstBoxResults.Items.Add("Year" & " " & year & " " & "Budget of Advertising Report")
    lstBoxResults.Items.Add(" ")
    lstBoxResults.Items.Add("=======================================")
    lstBoxResults.Items.Add(" ")
    lstBoxResults.Items.Add("Total Estimated Cost : " & FormatCurrency(txtBoxEstimatedCost.Text))
    lstBoxResults.Items.Add(" ")
    lstBoxResults.Items.Add("Total Estimated Budget : " & FormatCurrency(txtBoxEstimatedBudget.Text))
    lstBoxResults.Items.Add(" ")
    lstBoxResults.Items.Add("Selected Media : " & selectedMedia)
    lstBoxResults.Items.Add(" ")
    lstBoxResults.Items.Add("Number of Agencies Involved : " & numberOfAgencies)
    lstBoxResults.Items.Add(" ")
    lstBoxResults.Items.Add("=======================================")

End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Okay, so which bit are you stuck on?

Comment: I am having a problem writing the sub procedure to get the balance!

Comment: If the question is answered correctly, mark the correct answer as "accepted". Don't just obliterate the question text.

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/q/15604208/945456

Answer (score 0):

## Update

Your inputboxes are incorrect, if an invalid value is entered consistently the routine will drop through to the next lines of code!

They should appear as below.

```
Do
  inputtedData = InputBox("Please Enter a balance for SAVINGS account between $500.00 and $3000.00", "Initial Savings Balance", "0.00")
  If inputtedData = "" Then
    MsgBox("User chose to Cancel calculation!")
    Exit Sub
  Else
    initialBalanceSavings = CType(inputtedData, Single)
    If initialBalanceSavings > 3000 Or initialBalanceSavings < 500 Then MsgBox("Please enter a balance for SAVINGS account equal to or above $500.00 and no more than $3000.00", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error")
  End If
Loop Until initialBalanceSavings >= 500 And initialBalanceSavings <= 3000

Do
  inputtedData = InputBox("Please Enter a balance for CORPORATE account between $500.00 and $3000.00", "Initial Corporate Balance", "0.00")
  If inputtedData = "" Then
    MsgBox("User chose to Cancel calculation!")
    Exit Sub
  Else
    initialBalanceCorporate = CType(inputtedData, Single)
    If initialBalanceCorporate > 3000 Or initialBalanceCorporate < 500 Then MsgBox("Please enter a balance for CORPORATE account equal to or above $500.00 and no more than $3000.00", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error")
  End If
Loop Until initialBalanceCorporate >= 500 And initialBalanceCorporate <= 3000
```

Finally all the code is DEFINATELY NOT in the "btnMediaEstimatedFund" Procedure, as there is no calculation for the total values, neither is any consideration given to the fact that the calculation is for FUTURE years. in fact the KEY CALCULATION portions are missing!

What I mean is if you wish to generate a calculated figure for the year 2016, and now is 2013, then where is your accounting for the interest at 7% and 5%? I cannot see anywhere where it actually get calculated.

the subroutine which you "Dont know" how to create is no different from the subroutines you have created for your button/textbox/listbox events!

You pass parameters in and it does the calculation and if it is a SUB thats the end of it! and if it is a function then it returns a value or an object.

To create a Sub routine you give it a name an a list of parameters, if neccessary, you may have subroutines and functions without parameters but a function must ALWAYS return a value/object.

```
Sub ThisIsMySubroutine(MyParam1 as string, My Param2 as Object)
   ' code here
End Sub


Function ThisIsMyFunction(MyParam1 as string, My Param2 as Object) As Boolean
   ' code here
End Function
```

I'm sure you know already that the parameter and return data types can be any acceptable or recognized data types.

## Update II

With regards to your last comment (beginning with.. Also, I am having one small..) If you swap the code and put your ORIGINAL code back, you will STILL have that same issue!

Okay, so one last more code sample and pointer.

So to stop your program (10% yours 90% mine hahaha) from asking for the input you can enclose it in an if statement...

```
If checkBoxSavings.Checked Then
  Do
    inputtedData = InputBox("Please Enter a balance for SAVINGS account between $500.00 and $3000.00", "Initial Savings Balance", "0.00")
    If inputtedData = "" Then
      MsgBox("User chose to Cancel calculation!")
      Exit Sub
    Else
      initialBalanceSavings = CType(inputtedData, Single)
      If initialBalanceSavings > 3000 Or initialBalanceSavings < 500 Then MsgBox("Please enter a balance for SAVINGS account equal to or above $500.00 and no more than $3000.00", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error")
    End If
  Loop Until initialBalanceSavings >= 500 And initialBalanceSavings <= 3000
End If

If checkBoxCorporate.Checked Then
  Do
    inputtedData = InputBox("Please Enter a balance for CORPORATE account between $500.00 and $3000.00", "Initial Corporate Balance", "0.00")
    If inputtedData = "" Then
      MsgBox("User chose to Cancel calculation!")
      Exit Sub
    Else
      initialBalanceCorporate = CType(inputtedData, Single)
      If initialBalanceCorporate > 3000 Or initialBalanceCorporate < 500 Then MsgBox("Please enter a balance for CORPORATE account equal to or above $500.00 and no more than $3000.00", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error")
    End If
  Loop Until initialBalanceCorporate >= 500 And initialBalanceCorporate <= 3000
End If
```

And for the interest here is a link for you,
http://math.about.com/od/businessmath/ss/Interest.htm

Its an EXCEPTIONALLY good explanation because it shows the interest over more than 1 year, which is what this part of your question is asking...

**Please be aware of the current year, 2013. Now, the report is prepared in year 2013, but the balance should be calculated for your selected year (e.g., 2015, 2016, 2017). Think about the topic of repetition to determine the ending balance during your selected year**

Comment: How exactly would I calculate the total balance, if balance = balance * (1 + interestRate) from my above code since I have it wrong?

Comment: I am suppose to calculate the balance by pulling it from the check box they choose (Savings, Corporate, or both) and the balance they input into the msgBox!  Please Help!

Comment: Also, I am having one small problem with the code that you provided.  It is asking me to input the "Saving" and "Corporate" balance, even if the user only checks the "Saving" checkbox.  Do you kind of understand what I am saying?  The user should only be asked to enter the account type that he checks in the checkbox!  Thanks so much for all of your help!