# Getting balance from code in button

Tags: vb.net

I am having a little bit of trouble calculating the balance in my code.

In this program `(balance = balance * (1 + interestRate)`. The thing is that we are in 2013 and the balance will be calculated for the year 2015-2017, which is picked by a checkbox the user clicks in the program, and also the user picks what type of account they will have (Ie *Savings: 7% interest*, *Corporate: 5% interest*).

They will then click the `mediaEstimatedFund` button and it will ask them to enter a balance for the type of account that they chose (*Savings, Corporate*, or both). It should then calculate the balance for the (*Year*, *Account*, and *Balance amount*) that they chose.

Here is the code I have and it is not giving me the right balances (Example: If the user chose $2000.00, a *Savings* account at 7% and the year 2016, it should give me the estimated budget of $2621.60), but it is not!

```
Year     Savings Account                Corporate Account         Saving + Corporate    

2013       $2000.00                  $1000.00                   $3000.00
2014       $2140.00                  $1050.00                   $3190.00
2015       $2289.8                   $1102.5                    $3392.3
2016       $2450.086                 $1157.625                  $3607.711      
2017       $2621.59202               $1215.50625                $3837.09827

Public Class Form1

Private Sub btnMediaEstimatedFund_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnMediaEstimatedFund.Click

    Dim interestRate, initialBalanceSavings, initialBalanceCorporate, finalBalance, theYear, balance, subTotal As Double

    txtBoxEstimatedBudget.Enabled = False
    txtBoxAgenciesNeeded.Enabled = False

    If radButtonTraditional.Checked Then

        txtBoxAgenciesNeeded.Text = 3

    ElseIf radButtonEMedia.Checked Then

        txtBoxAgenciesNeeded.Text = 2

    End If

    If checkBoxSavings.Checked Then

        interestRate = 0.07

    ElseIf checkBoxCorporate.Checked Then

        interestRate = 0.05

    ElseIf checkBoxCorporate.Checked And checkBoxSavings.Checked Then

        interestRate = 0.12

    End If

    If radButton2015.Checked Then

        theYear = 2015

    End If

    If radButton2016.Checked Then

        theYear = 2016

    End If

    If radButton2017.Checked Then

        theYear = 2017

    End If

    Dim inputtedData As String

    If checkBoxSavings.Checked Then
        Do

            inputtedData = InputBox("Please enter a balance for SAVINGS account between $500.00 and $3000.00", "Initial Savings Balance", "0.00")

            If inputtedData = "" Then

                MsgBox("User chose to cancel calculation!")

                Exit Sub

            Else

                initialBalanceSavings = CType(inputtedData, Single)

                If initialBalanceSavings > 3000 Or initialBalanceSavings < 500 Then MsgBox("Please enter a balance for SAVINGS account equal to or above $500.00 and no more than $3000.00", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error")

            End If

        Loop Until initialBalanceSavings >= 500 And initialBalanceSavings <= 3000

    End If

    If checkBoxCorporate.Checked Then

        Do

            inputtedData = InputBox("Please enter a balance for CORPORATE account between $500.00 and $3000.00", "Initial Corporate Balance", "0.00")

            If inputtedData = "" Then

                MsgBox("User chose to Cancel calculation!")

                Exit Sub

            Else

                initialBalanceCorporate = CType(inputtedData, Single)

                If initialBalanceCorporate > 3000 Or initialBalanceCorporate < 500 Then MsgBox("Please enter a balance for CORPORATE account equal to or above $500.00 and no more than $3000.00", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error")

            End If

        Loop Until initialBalanceCorporate >= 500 And initialBalanceCorporate <= 3000

    End If

    finalBalance = initialBalanceSavings + initialBalanceCorporate

    For theYear = 2013 To 2017

        subTotal = finalBalance * (1 + interestRate)
        finalBalance = subTotal

    Next

    txtBoxEstimatedBudget.Text = FormatCurrency(finalBalance)

End Sub
```

Comment: It is giving me $2420.00

Comment: Me too... How do you, yourself, come to the result of 2621.6? Your formula doesn't seem to take accrued interest into account. Do you expect to update your code at NewYears? In 2014, checking 2015 shouldn't give `time = 2`, should it?

Comment: No, I don't intend on updating it....

Comment: You're right, I have the the math wrong in the code itself, i felt like it should be a loop.. But im not sure... do you mind helping me try and figure it out? It needs to involve accrued interest but I am unaware as to how to implement that into code into my program.

Comment: I came by doing (2000 * 1.07 = 2140, 2140 * 1.07 = 2289.80, 2289.80 * 1.07 = 2450.086, 2450.086 * 1.07 = 2621.60) , that is in sequence from year 2013-2016.

Comment: [DUPLICATE] Incidentally: This is the SAME QUESTION from here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15591114/assistance-creating-a-sub-procedure-named-fundingresourcebalance-visual-ba/15594462#comment22114436_15594462  but it looks like its a a DIFFERENT user name!

Answer (score 1):

```
For TheYear = 2013 to 2016
  SubTotal = balance * (1 + interestRate)
  balance = SubTotal
Next
```

## UPDATE

The code block above is just to give you an IDEA of HOW to do the loop and what should be calculated INSIDE the loop. To get the actual ANSWER you MUST remember that 2013 is the CURRENT year so you would not ACTUALLY calculate the interest for that year. And key to the way in which you accomplish this is the formatting of your loop, which in reality should begin the FOLLOWING year.

```
For Year = 2013 + 1 to 2016
  'blah blah blah
Next
```

Comment: I just posted an edit of my code with that for loop in, but still did not fix the problem? Did I do something wrong?  Thanks!

Comment: @Boom You have to move the line `finalBalance = initialBalanceSavings + initialBalanceCorporate` out of the loop. I edited Zaf's answer to indicate this.

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't allowed to edit Zafs answer to include the extra line, so here is my take. The important point being that the initialization of `finalBalance` is **outside** of the for-loop.

```
finalBalance = initialBalanceSavings + initialBalanceCorporate
For theYear = 2013 To 2016
  subtotal = finalBalance * (1 + interestRate)
  finalBalance = subTotal
Next
```

Comment: I just edited my code..... Does the code that I have take into account the years 2013 and 2014?

Comment: I am getting $2805.10 for (Savings account 7%) for each year(2015-2017) that the user picks.  I should be getting a different answer for each year.... but i'm not!

Comment: I edited it again to include what the calculation should come out too! I very much appreciate all of your help!

Comment: @Boom Please don't overwrite answers to say the question has been answered.