# Two balance won't add up if both checkboxes are checked

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am writing a program that should calculate the balance with the given information (Which checkbox they choose (Savings (7%), Corporate(5%), or both, then the year they choose (2015, 2016, 2017), and lastly the amount they put in when cued to enter balance (And that is based on what type of account they choose in the first step).  I have gotten all of the totals to show up correctly, except for when they choose both account types (Savings and Corporate).  To me their should be a line that just adds the two totals if both are chosen, but that isn't the case.  At least for me it isn't.

The total I get if I enter the balance of $2000 for savings and choose year 2015 the total is $2289.80 which is correct and then if I choose 2015 for the corporate account and enter $1000 the total is $1102.50.  So if I chose both of the accounts and entered the same numbers but checked both checkboxes I get $3434.70, but I should get $3392.30!

Here is the code I have, any help would be much appreciated! ( I think it might literally be just one line of code and it is killing me!)

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub btnMediaEstimatedFund_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnMediaEstimatedFund.Click

    Dim interestRate, initialBalanceSavings, initialBalanceCorporate, finalBalance, year, theYear, subTotal As Double
    Dim savingsInterestRate As Double = 0
    Dim corporateInterestRate As Double = 0
    Dim savingsSubTotal As Double = 0
    Dim corporateSubTotal As Double = 0

    txtBoxEstimatedBudget.Enabled = False
    txtBoxAgenciesNeeded.Enabled = False


    If radButtonTraditional.Checked Then

        txtBoxAgenciesNeeded.Text = 3

    ElseIf radButtonEMedia.Checked Then

        txtBoxAgenciesNeeded.Text = 2

    End If


    If checkBoxSavings.Checked Then

        savingsInterestRate = 0.07

    ElseIf checkBoxCorporate.Checked Then

        corporateInterestRate = 0.05
    End If


    If checkBoxSavings.Checked = False And checkBoxCorporate.Checked = False Then

        MsgBox("Please chose an account type to proceed!", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error")

    End If


    If radButton2015.Checked Then

        theYear = 2015

    ElseIf radButton2016.Checked Then

        theYear = 2016

    ElseIf radButton2017.Checked Then

        theYear = 2017

    End If


    Dim inputtedData As String

    If checkBoxSavings.Checked Then
        Do

            inputtedData = InputBox("Please enter a balance for SAVINGS account between $500.00 and $3000.00", "Initial Savings Balance", "0.00")

            If inputtedData = "" Then

                MsgBox("User chose to cancel calculation!")

                Exit Sub

            Else

                initialBalanceSavings = CType(inputtedData, Single)

                If initialBalanceSavings > 3000 Or initialBalanceSavings < 500 Then MsgBox("Please enter a balance for SAVINGS account equal to or above $500.00 and no more than $3000.00", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error")

            End If

        Loop Until initialBalanceSavings >= 500 And initialBalanceSavings <= 3000

    End If

    If checkBoxCorporate.Checked Then

        Do

            inputtedData = InputBox("Please enter a balance for CORPORATE account between $500.00 and $3000.00", "Initial Corporate Balance", "0.00")

            If inputtedData = "" Then

                MsgBox("User chose to Cancel calculation!")

                Exit Sub

            Else

                initialBalanceCorporate = CType(inputtedData, Single)

                If initialBalanceCorporate > 3000 Or initialBalanceCorporate < 500 Then MsgBox("Please enter a balance for CORPORATE account equal to or above $500.00 and no more than $3000.00", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error")

            End If

        Loop Until initialBalanceCorporate >= 500 And initialBalanceCorporate <= 3000

    End If


    savingsSubTotal = initialBalanceSavings
    corporateSubTotal = initialBalanceCorporate

    For year = 2013 To theYear - 1

        If savingsInterestRate > 0 Then

            savingsSubTotal = savingsSubTotal * (1 + savingsInterestRate)

        End If

        If corporateInterestRate > 0 Then

            corporateSubTotal = corporateSubTotal * (1 + corporateInterestRate)

        End If

    Next

    finalBalance = savingsSubTotal + corporateSubTotal
    txtBoxEstimatedBudget.Text = FormatCurrency(finalBalance)

End Sub
```

Comment: yes I did, its the last six lines of the code

Comment: DUPLICATE - I answered this question HERE http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15591114/assistance-creating-a-sub-procedure-named-fundingresourcebalance-visual-ba/15594462#comment22114436_15594462  and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15604208/getting-balance-from-code-in-button-edited-part-3/15605658#15605658 Already!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the erroneous logic is in this block of code:

```
finalBalance = initialBalanceSavings + initialBalanceCorporate

For year = 2013 To theYear - 1
    subTotal = finalBalance * (1 + interestRate)
    finalBalance = subTotal
Next
```

Combined with this block of code:

```
If checkBoxSavings.Checked Then
    interestRate = 0.07
ElseIf checkBoxCorporate.Checked Then
    interestRate = 0.05
End If
```

In the above, even if something checks **both** checkboxes the interest rate is set at 0.07 so in your loop if someone calculates 2015 you will do something like give you a final total of: `3000 * 1.07 * 1.07`, whereas you really want `(2000 * 1.07 * 1.07) + (1000 * 1.05 * 1.05)`

In essence because you only use one variable to hold the interest rate (as well as only having one variable to hold sub-totals) your code cannot account properly for a scenario where someone selects both accounts. I would suggest having 2 variables to hold the interest rates:

```
Dim savingsInterestRate as Double = 0
Dim corporateInterestRate as Double = 0
```

And 2 variables to hold the sub-totals:

```
Dim savingsSubTotal as Double = 0
Dim corporateSubTotal as Double = 0
```

And in your For loop do:

```
    savingsSubTotal = initialBalanceSavings
    corporateSubTotal = initialBalanceCorporate

    For year = 2013 To theYear - 1
        If savingsInterestRate > 0 Then
            savingsSubTotal = savingsSubTotal * (1 + savingsInterestRate)
        End If

        If corporateInterestRate > 0 Then
            corporateSubTotal = corporateSubTotal * (1 + corporateInterestRate)
        End If
    Next

    finalBalance = savingsSubTotal + corporateSubTotal
```

And change your interest rate check to:

```
If checkBoxSavings.Checked Then
    savingsInterestRate = 0.07
End If

If checkBoxCorporate.Checked Then
    corporateInterestRate = 0.05
End If
```

So you can account for the person's selection (using the `ElseIf` means that if they check both, it will discard the corporate rate since `checkBoxSavings.Checked` is already true sp it never falls into the `ElseIf` block)

Comment: I just edited my code If both boxes are checked and put 2000 for savings and 1000 for corporate and pick 2015 and I am getting 3289.80 but should be getting 3392.30.... Any help?